# Laravel Vapor PHP error while trying to upload file form front-end

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-vapor

> Error: Missing environment variables: AWS_BUCKET, AWS_DEFAULT_REGION, AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

i'm using laravel-vapor lib to upload files from the front-end because of his sizes(6.8mb)

my code to upload:

```
showAlert() {   
        alert("vou entrar");        
        try {
            
            Vapor.store(this.$refs.file.files[0], {
progress: progress => {
    this.uploadProgress = Math.round(progress * 100);
}
,visibility: 'public-read'
}).then(response => {
    axios.post('/api/tempmedia', {
        uuid: response.uuid,
        key: response.key,
        bucket: response.bucket,
        name: this.$refs.file.files[0].name,
        content_type: this.$refs.file.files[0].type,
    })
});
            } catch (error) {
                alert(error.message);
            }
```

My env:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="..."
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="..."
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=...
AWS_REGION=...
AWS_BUCKET=...
AWS_BUCKET_URL=...
```

My connection is correct because i've added files from the back-end before.

I already tried `php artisan config:cache` and `php artisan config:clear` but the error continues

Comment: It is because given variables are not set in your .env file.

Comment: as I mentioned above, apparently everything is fine with my .env file, I shared it above and it has the required fields

Comment: Do your fields have value also? Like `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=SOME_AWS_KEY`

Comment: the fields have correct values, I just changed them for points so as not to have sensitive content

Comment: Are you using multiple .env files? Can you pull your env by running command `vapor env:pull ENVIRONMENT_NAME` and see what is the content of `.env.ENVIRONMENT_NAME`. Does it have mentioned keys? Replace ENVIRONMENT_NAME with your environment.

Comment: I'm using two .env files
one with the name ".env" and another with the name: ".env.example"
to use this .env without the example, how would I do it? and to do the pull, would it be vapor env:pull example?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pull and then push the .env for the environment you are deploying to.
For production

```
vapor env:pull production
```

This will download a file(.env.production) that you can edit. Add your env variables as you would in your normal .env file. Then save and :

```
vapor env:push production
```

Then `vapor deploy production`